# Plotly Dash: Position the indicator title on the left of the number

Tags: python, position, plotly-dash, indicator

I would like to show different values with Plotly indicators *bullet*-style (*number+gauge*) and *number*-only in aligned rows in a Dash application.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to position the title of a *number*-only indicator left of the displayed number.
Is there a way to move the title to the left?

(I tried adding `'align': 'left'` into the title dict, however this only aligns the text but does not change the position.)

This is an example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

bullet_fig1 = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+gauge",
    value = 23,
    align = "left",
    domain = {'x': [0.25, 1], 'y': [0.45, .95]},
    number = {
        'suffix': " %",
    },
    title = {'text': "Load 1", 'font': {"size": 12},},
    gauge = {
        'shape': "bullet",
        'axis': {'range': [0, 100]},
        'bar': {
            'color': "red",
            'thickness': .7,
        },
    },
))
bullet_fig1.update_layout(height = 50, margin = {'t':0, 'b':0, 'l':0, 'r':0})

bullet_fig2 = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+gauge",
    value = 46,
    align = "left",
    domain = {'x': [0.25, 1], 'y': [0.45, .95]},
    number = {
        'suffix': " %",
    },
    title = {'text': "Load 2", 'font': {"size": 12},},
    gauge = {
        'shape': "bullet",
        'axis': {'range': [0, 100]},
        'bar': {
            'color': "red",
            'thickness': .7,
        },
    },
))
bullet_fig2.update_layout(height = 50, margin = {'t':0, 'b':0, 'l':0, 'r':0})

number_fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number",
    align = "left",
    value = 12,
    domain = {'x': [0.25, 1], 'y': [0.45, .95]},
    number = {
        'suffix': " °C",
    },
    title = {'text': "Temperature", 'font': {"size": 12},},
))
number_fig.update_layout(height = 50, margin = {'t':0, 'b':0, 'l':0, 'r':0})


bullet_fig1.show()
bullet_fig2.show()
number_fig.show()
```

[image]